# How to switch max and min elements in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

1. I create an array and fill it from the console.
2. I print that array in console.
3. I detect max and min elements in the array and output them in console.
4. Then I need to switch max and min elements and output the
   updated array (without creating a new one).
5. Optionally I need to output new array that contains switched (max and min) elements.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        int MaxElementIndex = 0;
        int MinElementIndex = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int[] t = new int[5];

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter {0} element array", i + 1);
            t[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        int max = t[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (max < t[i])
            {
                max = t[i];
                MaxElementIndex = i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("the maximum a value is equal {0} and index number is {1}", max, MaxElementIndex);
        int min = t[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (min > t[i])
            {
                min = t[i];
                MinElementIndex = i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("the minimun value is equal {0} and index number is {1}", min, MinElementIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("Initial array: ");
        foreach (var item in t)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Changed array:");
        MaxElementIndex = temp;
        MinElementIndex = MaxElementIndex;
        temp = MinElementIndex;
        foreach (var newItem in t)
        {
            Console.Write(newItem.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The problem is that I am not sure how to get the old array with switched elements. The pattern with temp variable returns me "0".

Comment: what do you mean by _switch max and min elements and output the updated array (without creating a new one)._ i didnt see you have updated the array. i didnt downvote.

Comment: If you vote down, please comment at least!

Comment: I need to switch MAX and MIN elements in the array and output the existing array in console.

Comment: You just remember their positions. Let's  say that max position is "i" and min position is "j" where i and j are indices in your array. After finding them, you have to do a simple switch using an additional variable, let's call it "aux". So aux = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = aux;

Comment: i undestand your question now. but the reason of downvotes is because you put extra information that is not needed. i think it was enough to ask how to replace two elements of array. but i didnt downvote anyway.

Comment: @AnastasiaLangovaya, sometimes you just can't win with downvoters. If you'd just asked how to swap the elements, they'd have moaned you weren't showing your code. You show the code and they moan there's too much ... have an upvote from me to offset those folk. I'd recommend accepting one of the two correct answers and moving on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are switching your temporary variables. But you want to switch you min and max elements in array. Your switching code should be like following:

```
temp = t[MaxElementIndex];
t[MaxElementIndex]=t[MinElementIndex];
t[MinElementIndex]=temp;
```

And then you should loop over your array:

```
Console.WriteLine("Switched array: ");
foreach (var newItem in t)
    {
        Console.Write(newItem.ToString());
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This section is wrong in your code:

```
Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("Changed array:");
MaxElementIndex = temp;
MinElementIndex = MaxElementIndex;
temp = MinElementIndex;
```

it should be:

```
Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("Changed array:");
temp = t[MaxElementIndex];
t[MaxElementIndex] = t[MinElementIndex];
t[MinElementIndex] = temp;
```

First you store your  t[maxElement] in temp variable then you replace it with t[minElement] and in the end replace minimum with maximum which is stored in temp variable.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't set 2 answers!